# Someone could help me with this error message "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'X'"

Tags: python

I need do obtain a standard matrix but I'm having some problems... Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/DESICHRIS/Desktop/INPUT.xlsx')
df.as_matrix()
print (df)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
# Get column names first
names = df.columns
# Create the Scaler object
scaler = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df)
# Fit your data on the scaler object
scaled_df = scaler.fit_transform(df)
scaled_df = pd.DataFrame(scaled_df, columns=names)
print (scaled_df)
```

Python shows an error message, as above:

```
File "c:/Users/DESICHRIS/Desktop/ATUAL TESE DESIREE/pesquisa Desiree/python/mteste.py", line 11, in 
scaled_df = scaler.fit_transform(df)
File "C:\Users\DESICHRIS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 464, in fit_transform
return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
File "C:\Users\DESICHRIS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 645, in fit
return self.partial_fit(X, y)
File "C:\Users\DESICHRIS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 669, in partial_fit
force_all_finite='allow-nan')
File "C:\Users\DESICHRIS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 527, in check_array
array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
File "C:\Users\DESICHRIS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'X'
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: The error is perfectly explicit: the column contains the string `'X'` which cannot be converted to a `float`. [`StandardScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) intends to perform numerical calculations on the data, which means that it must contain all numerical values.

Answer (score 1):

In your dataframe there are values that are marked with 'X' and not a float.
You can delete them using:

```
df = df.drop(df[(df.name_of_column == 'X')].index)
```

Comment: thanks! But now shows the message: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name_of_column'

Comment: name_of_column means the name of the column of your dataframe, I put that because I don't know it!